# downgrade or upgrade manjaro-openbox-theme-18.0?

Tags: manjaro, openbox

manjaro linux with openbox related question.

Updates via package manager just stop working properly, but it still possible to update the system via `sudo pacman -Syu`.

Via command line I get this question:

```
Replace manjaro-openbox-wallpapers-18.0 with community/manjaro-openbox-wallpapers? [Y/n]
```

If answer Y then the updates will be aborted, answering n the updates will proceed as usual.

My question is related to the error returned when trying to update via package manager:

```
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing manjaro-openbox-wallpapers-18.0 breaks dependency 'manjaro-openbox-wallpapers-18.0' required by manjaro-openbox-theme-18.0
```

The error seems pretty straight forward, but remove `manjaro-openbox-theme-18.0`, will crash the GUI.

I did try:

- remove `manjaro-openbox-wallpapers-18.0` but it is not allowed due to dependencies.
- update `manjaro-openbox-theme-18.0` also not allowed, it's already the most up to date version.

Downgrade to a previous version I didn't try yet.. Any ideas?

Comment: Packaging bug: report it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manjaro-openbox-theme-18.0 shows a few dependencies, including manjaro-openbox-wallpapers-18.0
but manjaro-openbox-wallpapers-18.0 shows no dependency back to manjaro-openbox-theme-18.0

problem package appears to be manjaro-openbox-wallpapers
that doesn't appear to relate to any other package, except for wanting to replace the package you need to keep

I don't see any sense to why one package of wallpapers would need to replace another
I suspect a bug in the package, or maybe wrong package got updated

you don't need to do anything immediately if this one package is not blocking other updates.
check it again in a day or 2 and refresh package database
problem may resolve itself if the packages get fixed or updated

If manjaro-openbox-wallpapers is preventing other updates, find the ignore upgrades list in package manager Preferences and add package name
that should allow you to upgrade everything else

suggest you advise the Manjaro openbox developers about possible bug with these packages
they will be able to check and fix anything and advise you when it is ok to clear the ignored packed

Comment: I just reported with the manjaro community the issue as a possible bug with the the manjaro openbox. Thanks.